# connecting to kongregate api

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Just checking to see if anyone uses kongregate. If so, I am having issues.

When I connect to kongregate locally on debug mode it works fine. but when I upload the game to their servers, I get the following error.

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
at com.objects::Engine/GameMenu()
at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
```

Below is the code I use. and the class properties i set

```
// Kongregate API reference
        private var kongregate:*;

public function Engine(sr:Stage):void
        {
            // Pull the API path from the FlashVars
            var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(sr.loaderInfo).parameters;

            // The API path. The "shadow" API will load if testing locally. 
            var apiPath:String = paramObj.kongregate_api_path || 
              "http://www.kongregate.com/flash/API_AS3_Local.swf";

            // Allow the API access to this SWF
            Security.allowDomain(apiPath);

            // Load the API
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(apiPath);
            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
            loader.load(request);
            this.addChild(loader);

            var music:MusicBackGround = new MusicBackGround();
            music.play(0,int.MAX_VALUE);
            this.sr = sr;
            init();
        }
```

here is the handler

```
// This function is called when loading is complete
        function loadComplete(event:Event):void
        {
            // Save Kongregate API reference
            kongregate = event.target.content;

            // Connect to the back-end
            kongregate.services.connect();

            // You can now access the API via:
            // kongregate.services
            // kongregate.user
            // kongregate.scores
            // kongregate.stats
            // etc...
        }
```

below is the line of code that triggers the error

```
var isGuest:Boolean = kongregate.services.isGuest();
            var username:String = kongregate.services.getUsername();
            menu.MenuInfo.text = "Kongregate Edition\nWelcome, "+username;
```

Comment: nevermind. the issue is because it called on menu, before the loadComplete event was finsihed.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be this line:

`var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(sr.loaderInfo).parameters;`

Kong loads your movie into their swf, so the parameters may not exist at that level.
Try:

```
var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(root.loaderInfo).parameters;
```

The change is a reference to root where I expect the parameters should be found.

Also: can you post what your error message is?